# checking if string is generated by regular grammar

Tags: regular-languages

How do I check wether a string is generated by given regular grammar?
I know you can check for it in O(N), what is the algorithm called?

Comment: What is $N$? Note that you have two input arguments: a string and a regular grammar. Anyway, is [this wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times) helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular grammar corresponds quite closely to a non-deterministic finite automaton, reading the word in the usual way (right regular grammar) or backwards (left regular grammar). You can run $m$-state NFAs on inputs of length $n$ in complexity $O(2^m n)$, which is linear if you fix the NFA.